# Automapper ignore property on generics mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

This generic method works fine :

```
public static U PropertyAutomapper<T, U>(T source)
    where T : class, new()
    where U : class, new()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(T), typeof(U));
    return Mapper.Map<T, U>(source);
}
```

I have this interface :

```
public interface IPassword
{
    string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like ignore this property ('`Password`')but I don't have 'ignore' in the intelissense

```
public static U PropertyAutomapperNoPassword<T, U>(T source)
    where T : IPassword
    where U : IPassword
{
    Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(T), typeof(U))...   
    return Mapper.Map<T, U>(source);
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<T, U>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Password, opt => opt.Ignore())
```